# prestashop regenerate category tree to c#

Tags: c#, arrays, multidimensional-array, prestashop

I am trying to translate the Prestashop php code to c# but I can't figure it out about the array.
This part is the original code from Prestashop 1.7.6

```
$id = Context::getContext()->shop->id;
        $idShop = $id ? $id : Configuration::get('PS_SHOP_DEFAULT');
        $sql = new DbQuery();
        $sql->select('c.`id_category`, c.`id_parent`');
        $sql->from('category', 'c');
        $sql->leftJoin('category_shop', 'cs', 'c.`id_category` = cs.`id_category` AND cs.`id_shop` = ' . (int) $idShop);
        $sql->orderBy('c.`id_parent`, cs.`position` ASC');
        $categories = Db::getInstance()->executeS($sql);
        $categoriesArray = array();
        foreach ($categories as $category) {
            $categoriesArray[$category['id_parent']]['subcategories'][] = $category['id_category'];
        }
```

I created a test file to show the output which gives this (for example)

```
Array ( [0] => Array ( [subcategories] => Array ( [0] => 1 ) ) 
[1] => Array ( [subcategories] => Array ( [0] => 2 ) ) 
[2] => Array ( [subcategories] => Array ( [0] => 324 [1] => 3089 [2] => 394 [3] => 3110 [4] => 540 [5] => 3120 [6] => 667 [7] => 3145 [8] => 3 [9] => 1082 [10] => 3185 [11] => 26 [12] => 1125 [13] => 3792 [14] => 36 [15] => 1198 [16] => 48 [17] => 1310 [18] => 53 [19] => 1409 [20] => 63 [21] => 1456 [22] => 102 [23] => 2482 [24] => 210 [25] => 2517 [26] => 219 [27] => 2564 [28] => 238 [29] => 3069 [30] => 298 [31] => 3072 [32] => 308 [33] => 3075 ) ) 
[3] => Array ( [subcategories] => Array ( [0] => 1450 [1] => 2826 [2] => 3060 [3] => 3063 [4] => 4 [5] => 9 [6] => 12 [7] => 17 [8] => 19 [9] => 21 [10] => 30 [11] => 40 [12] => 51 [13] => 58 ) ) )
```

I tried it with a dictionary and added some classes to add the multidimensional array's but it won't work unfortunally. This is what I tried so far:

```
public bool ReGenerateEntireTree()
        {
            Database db = new Database();
            db.DbConnect();
            DataTable table = new DataTable();
            string query = "";
            query = "SELECT c.`id_category`, c.`id_parent` FROM `ps_category` c LEFT JOIN `ps_category_shop` cs " +
                    "ON c.`id_category` = cs.`id_category` AND cs.`id_shop` = 1 " +
                    "ORDER BY c.`id_parent`, cs.`position` ASC;";
            table = db.SelectWebsiteQuery(query);
            Dictionary<int, SubCategories> categoryArray = new Dictionary<int, SubCategories>();
            
            
            int categoryIndex = 0;
            for (int i = 0; i < table.Rows.Count; i++)
            {
                int id_category = Convert.ToInt32(table.Rows[i]["id_category"]);
                int id_parent = Convert.ToInt32(table.Rows[i]["id_parent"]);
                
                if(!categoryArray.ContainsKey(id_parent))
                {
                    SubCategories sCategories = new SubCategories();
                    categoryIndex = 0;
                    sCategories.subCategories = "categories";
                    Categories Cat = new Categories
                    {
                        Index = categoryIndex,
                        CategoryIndex = id_category
                    };
                    sCategories.Categories = new Categories[2];
                    sCategories.Categories[categoryIndex].Index = categoryIndex;
                    sCategories.Categories[categoryIndex].CategoryIndex = id_category;
                    categoryArray.Add(id_parent, sCategories);
                    categoryIndex++;
                }
                else
                {
                    SubCategories sCategories = new SubCategories();
                    sCategories.subCategories = "categories";
                    Categories Cat = new Categories();
                    Cat.Index = categoryIndex;
                    Cat.CategoryIndex = id_category;
                    sCategories.Categories[categoryIndex] = Cat;
                    categoryArray[id_parent].Categories[categoryIndex] = Cat;
                    categoryIndex++;
                }
            }
            int n = 1;
            
            return true;
        }
```

```
public class SubCategories
    {
        public string subCategories {get; set;}
        public Categories[] Categories { get; set; }
    }
    public class Categories
    {
        public int Index;
        public int CategoryIndex;
    }
```